# Merging two Comps, Adobe After Effects

Tags: after-effects

I want to merge two comps in after effects so, when I play contents from both layers shows.

At the current time the upper composition dont allow the lower composition to display its contents.

Comment: Welcome Ali :) I'd like to help, but I don't really understand your issue. Just to get it right: You want to create 1 comp by 2 other comps to get all in one? If yes, make sure the comp above has an alpha channel (transparency). Maybe you could add a screenshot... Anyway, enjoy video.se!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that you have two compositions in one main composition, and you want both to show their contents on **top** of each other, then I can help you.

Make sure that you click on "Toggle Switches / Modes",

[image]

so that you have the "Mode" option available.

[image]

Now set the top composition to either "Screen", "Add", or "Lighten".

[image]

Make sure that the top composition has at least some transparent part in it, if it's just a full solid black layer, nothing's going to show through be default, unless you lower the opacity down.